# Using meteor.js together with react-three

Tags: meteor, reactjs, three.js

I am trying to try running meteor together with react and react-three library, that wraps three.js for react. As there are no atmosphere package for this, I am looking into either wrapping it myself or any other method how to use it.

1) How to wrap react-three library into meteor package?
I have tried downloading [react-three](https://github.com/Izzimach/react-three) repo, running `npm run build` and then using resulting react-three.js with package code written like this:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "react-three wrapped",
  version: "0.8.0",
  name: "myname:react-three",
});

Npm.depends({
  "react-three": "0.8.0"
});

Package.on_use(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom("0.9.0");

  api.use('limemakers:three@=0.73.0',['client','server']);

  api.add_files([
    "lib/react-three.js"
  ]);

  api.export("THREE");
  api.export("ReactTHREE");
});
```

but this does not seem to do the deal, no ReactTHREE is exported. Might be because of the way react-three build process works. Could you point me into the direction on how to build and wrap it properly?

2) Maybe it is possible to use it directly? 
I tried [meteorhacks:npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm), but it seems that it is server side only. Anything else that could work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor 1.3-beta was just released and it has support for js modules, although I haven't had the opportunity to test it.
This article has good documentation.
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release-1.3/packages/modules/README.md

Comment: yeah, looks like it is the only option. and that makes me dependent on beta release, with unknown production data :/